# How to stop a background process started in the same script, without exit the script?

Tags: bash, shell-script, background-process

I have a program that takes a variable time to run (no more than two minutes), and to make it less odious, I put fortune messages.

```
 #!/bin/bash
 ...
 for i in $(seq 1 45); do sleep 3; echo; echo; fortune; done &
 ...
```

However, the program duration may vary (depending on factors that are irrelevant here) and need to stop the messages.

```
 #!/bin/bash
 ...
 for i in $(seq 1 45); do sleep 3; echo; echo; fortune; done &
 ...
 if [any-condition]; Then
      #script is over... Stop messages!!!
 fi
 ...
 if [any-condition]; Then
      #Stop messages... script continue execution
 fi
 ... Blah blah
 ...
 #script is over stop Messages!
```

So if I prepare 45 messages in periods of 3 seconds, the program may end soon but the messages still appear in the terminal, interfering with other work.

I try with command `jobs`, but there are no jobs in background. Try with command `ps` but can't found the messages task.

How to stop that fortune messages?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The simplest way is to use `$!`. That is the PID of the last process launched in the background (from `man bash`):

> !
>
> Expands  to  the  process  ID  of  the  job most recently placed into the background, whether executed as an asynchronous command or using the bg
>   builtin.

So, you could do something like:

```bash
for i in $(seq 1 45); do sleep 3; echo; echo; fortune; done &
pid=$!

[ main script here]

if [any-condition]; then
  kill $pid
fi
```

However, I can't help thinking this is a rather convoluted way of doing things. I could give you a more specific example if you showed your whole script,  but why not something like:

```
long_process &
while ps -p $! >/dev/null; do sleep 3; echo; echo; fortune; done
```

That would let you launch whatever process takes that long and will run `fortune` until it ends.